# android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 0

Tags: android, database, sqlite, cursor

```
android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 0
```

while placing debugger in the the method it is not going after the line

```
   double lans = c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndex(LAN));
     double  lons = c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndex(LON));
```

Can any one help me to solve it

```
public Locationxy getData(int id , DataBaseHelper dbHelper ) {
   SQLiteDatabase dbo = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
   Locationxy locationxy=new Locationxy();


   String[] coulmns = new String[]{BumpID, LAN, LON};
   String[] args = new String[]{String.valueOf(id)};
   Cursor c = dbo.query(TABLE_BUMPS, coulmns, BumpID + "=?",args, null, null, null, null);

   if ((c !=null ) && c.getCount()>0 )
       c.moveToFirst();
      double lans = c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndex(LAN));
     double  lons = c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndex(LON));

       locationxy = new Locationxy(lans, lons);





    return locationxy ;
```

}
}

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
if ((c !=null ) && c.moveToFirst() && c.getColumnCount()>2){
  double lans = c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndex(LAN));
 double  lons = c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndex(LON));
 locationxy = new Locationxy(lans, lons);
}
```

Points to consider:

- You have put the "if" without brackets, so the second line (where lons is setted) is called even when the cursor is null.
- The c.getCount()>0 is not necessary, just calling c.moveToFirst() ist enough to check if the cursor is greather than 0.
- The getColumnCount()>2 checks if the cursor has the necessary columns (looking at your code looks like the cursor has 3 columns, so I check if it is greather than 2)

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: I changed my code, after line `double lans = c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndex(LAN));` the application is stopped java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.

Comment: Be sure that LAN and LON are exactly the same names of the columns in the database (is possible that there is a mistake in the string)

Comment: its exactly the same names :((

Answer (score -1):

Please take care of the if statement without { }. Here you are just doing the condition on the `c.moveToFirst()`.

After a query, the returned cursor [start at the position -1](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) . So if your cursor's count is equal to 0, you will never call cursor.moveToFirst.

The good way to implement your code is:

```
Cursor c = null;
try {
    c = dbo.query...
    if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
        //Here your cursor is at the first position is not empty
        double lans = c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(LAN));
        double lons = c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(LON));
        locationxy = new Locationxy(lans, lons);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    //Log.e(); log of any exception;
} finally {
    //don't forget to close your cursor.
    if (c != null) {
        c.close();
    }
}   
return locationxy;
```

**Edit:**
You can try with getColumnIndexOrThrow to be sure that the name of your column is right.

Comment: i cahnged my code , Failed to read row 0, column -1 from aCursorWindow which has 1 rows, 3 columns.

Comment: Please verify that the name of your columns is right. They should be the same as when you created the table TABLE_BUMPS.

Comment: it is right ! ` public static final String DB_name = "LocationDB"; public static final String TABLE_BUMPS = "BUMPS"; public static final String BumpID = "BumpID"; public static final String LON = "Lon"; public static final String LAN = "Lan"; @Override public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) { String CREATE_QUERY = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_BUMPS +" (" + BumpID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY , "+ LAN + " DOUBLE , "+ LON + " DOUBLE " +")"; db.execSQL(CREATE_QUERY); `

Comment: no error appear after this  line ... double lans = c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(LAN));
        double lons = c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(LON));

Comment: How do you insert your data ?

Comment: <pre> public void putInformation(Locationxy locationxy) {
  SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
   values.put(LAN, locationxy.getLan());
    values.put(LON, locationxy.getLon());
db.insert(TABLE_BUMPS, null, values);
     db.close();
    } <code>

Comment: **mainclass
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
double lan1[] = new double[]{32.31222487966547, 32.312272639917154, 32.31247837186454, 32.30554477248256 , 32.31105001665195 , 32.31094754741438};
          double lon1[] = new double[]{35.02060431138064, 35.02184001899962, 35.0214652067116, 35.02243864991221 , 35.02843974572994 , 35.02852285972824};
context = getApplicationContext();
        dbHelper =new DataBaseHelper(context);
        for(int j=0;j<=5;j++) {
       dbHelper.putInformation(new Locationxy( lan1[j], lon1[j]));

Comment: When you do db.insert(...), check if the result return is not -1. -1 means there is an error. You can also use insertOrThrow see if there is an exception.